# AWS S3 - managing permissions based on Cognito token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have a bunch of files in an S3 bucket.
I know i can create a bucket policy to allow access to certain Roles/ User pools (forget the specific terminology at the moment)

How do i get it so I can authenticate a user using JWT token issued from cognito?

e.g. lets say one of the files is an image on s3
in order for a user to access the file, the http request needs to include the token in the HTTP request header somehow. S3 looks at request and if token meets bucket policy, it allows the download.

An example/guide of how to implement this would be appreciated

Comment: You can create a group in cognito, Based on user belongs to that group can access the image.
Group value will be available in the IdToken of cognito.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Get the token or session credentials for Cognito user? Write policy? Authorize users using Cognito? Btw here is a policy allowing users to access the S3 object starting with their username https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html   I haven't find any policy restricting based on an user group so far (I believe the policy attribute needs to be propagated as a user claim, not as group membership, but here I may be mistaken)

Comment: @jayeshDhandha can access be based on a custom claim in the token?

Comment: Yes that's also a good option. You can have that value in the IdToke.